# Cannot get the has_key method to work in python

Tags: python

I don't understand why I'm getting an attribute error in the following:

```
jim = {}
jim.update({"hey":2})
if jim.has_key("hey"):
    print ('hey')
```

here's a screen shot:

[image]

[image]

Comment: There is no has_key in python Instead use `if key in dict.keys`

Comment: @Madhusudanchowdary no, that will *always be `False`.* You need to *call `keys`, so `if key in some_dict.keys()`, but that is an anti-pattern. In Python 2, it creates a whole new list, and does a membership test on a list, which is linear time instead of constant time. In Python 3, `keys()` returns a view, so you don't lose that, but it is merely redundant. Just use `if some_key in some_dict:`

Comment: Out of curiosity, where did you learn about using the `has_key` method? Even in Python2 land, this method has been deprecated since 2002.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That method was deprecated in Python 3. Use

`some_key in some_dict`

To test the membership of a key in a dictionary.

So, for your example:

```
if "hey" in jim:
    print("hey")
```